# How to search filter in vue.js based on id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am making a Vue project. It contains a `div` and it loops title and
 data. Inside div there is a search filter and content which renders in `p` tags. The `p` tags also
 loops.

Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <div v-for="(item) in data" :key="item.id">
        <div>{{item.title}}</div>
        <input type="text" v-model="search" />
        <div v-for="(content, j) in filteredLists" :key="j">
            <p v-for="(con, k) in content" :key="k">{{con}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the data

```
search: "",
data: [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Devsrc",
        content: {
            id: 1,
            details: ["ONE_DEV_EMP1", "ONE_DEV_EMP2"]
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Devsrc2",
        content: {
            id: 2,
            details: ["TWO_DEV_EMP1", "TWO_DEV_EMP2"]
        }
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Devsrc3",
        content: {
            id: 3,
            details: ["THREE_DEV_EMP1", "THREE_DEV_EMP2"]
        }
    }
]
```

computed property

```
filteredLists() {
      return this.data.map(item => {
       return item.content.details.filter(detail => {
           return detail.toLowerCase().match(this.search);
       })
      });
    },
```

What I am trying to do is render details only for item id == content
 id.

Comment: For clarification: You are rendering multiple search fields and you want to filter only the details of each item by its search field? The items do not get filtered and all titles are displayed?

Comment: Yes, Absolutely

Answer (score 2):

Make `filteredLists()` a method instead of computed for starters.

```
<div>
    <div v-for="(item) in data" :key="item.id">
        <div>{{item.title}}</div>
        <input type="text" v-model="search" />
        <div v-for="(content, j) in filteredLists(item.id)" :key="j">
            <p v-for="(con, k) in content" :key="k">{{con}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
function filteredLists(id) {

  let term = this.search.trim().toUpperCase();
  let scoped = this.data.filter(item => { return parseInt(item.content.id) === parseInt(id) });

  if(term.length > 0) {
    return scoped.filter(item => {
      return item.content.details.find(seek => seek.match(search));
    });
  }

  return scoped;
}
```

```js
let search = 'EMP2';

let data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Devsrc",
    content: {
      id: 1,
      details: ["ONE_DEV_EMP1", "ONE_DEV_EMP2"]
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Devsrc2",
    content: {
      id: 2,
      details: ["TWO_DEV_EMP1", "TWO_DEV_EMP2"]
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Devsrc3",
    content: {
      id: 3,
      details: ["THREE_DEV_EMP1", "THREE_DEV_EMP2"]
    }
  }
];

function filteredLists(id) {

      let term = search.trim().toUpperCase();
      let scoped = data.filter(item => { return parseInt(item.content.id) === parseInt(id) });

      if(term.length > 0) {
        return scoped.filter(item => {
          return item.content.details.find(seek => seek.match(search));
        });
      }

      return scoped;
}

console.log(filteredLists(3));
```

Comment: I missed a couple of things before but i think i finally got the gist of what you are doing, that's my final answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
filteredLists() {
  return data.filter(
    function(item) {
      return item.content.details.find(
        function(detail) {
          return detail.toLowerCase().match(this.search)
        }.bind(this)
      )
    }.bind(this)
  )
}
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Please add an explanation for your code.